# Handling different screen sizes in multiplayer games

Tags: multiplayer, balance, fullscreen

sorry if this has been asked already. I did some checking around and couldn't find any helpful advice.

I'm developing my first multiplayer game, and it'll be fullscreen when run. My issue is, how do I balance for screen sizes? It seems to me that it might be considered unfair if some players can see more of the playing field than others, and it's not an issue I'd ever considered before since all my previous projects have been single player and usually fixed resolution.

Some options I'd thought of is a zoomable map, so players can handle how much of the screen they see to give them the choice between clarity and view distance. Another was a fixed internal resolution and black bars or sidebars if it's out of the aspect ratio.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is your game genre? For RTS you may want to use fog of war or just limit your viewport to fixed area, as you suggested yourself. For FPS or any action game your screen resolution doesn't really matters - they are based heavily on input precision and reaction, but not on observation.

Comment: Top-down action/brawler game. I guess you're right, but part of the concern was related to things like pickups being spawned, especially in large-map, low-player-count scenarios where people with larger screens have a higher chance of noticing and getting the choice pickups.